# Web.config transformations

Tags: asp.net, web-config, web.config-transform

I know we can do a transformation when deploying to different environments or settings using the web.config transformations in the below style but my question is is it possible to replace another section of the web.config completely with this technique or some other settings.For example i have a `<System.IdentityModel> </System.IdentityModel>` section that I would like to completely change when deploying to different environments.Is it possible .

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <!--
    In the example below, the "SetAttributes" transform will change the value of 
    "connectionString" to use "ReleaseSQLServer" only when the "Match" locator 
    finds an attribute "name" that has a value of "MyDB".

    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyDB" 
        connectionString="Data Source=ReleaseSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;Integrated Security=True" 
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
  -->

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a project on NuGet called ConfigZilla which can replace entire sections in config files. It works by processing a `.template.config` into a `.config` file, and you can do any Xslt transformation in there. There is an example here http://philipdaniels.com/configzilla/templates.html

ConfigZilla takes a slightly different approach compared to web config transforms, I have tried hard to centralize the configuration so that it is more scalable.